# Recursive code for finding the first to be in wrong order Python

Tags: python

I wrote 2 codes, iterative and recursive, that should return the first number that's smaller then the last, i.e. the first to be in the wrong order in the list.

Iterative code, running fine:

```
def out_of_order(lst):
    before = 0
    for y in lst:
        if y < before:
            return y
        before = y
print(out_of_order([1,5,17,12,24]))
```

return value is `12`.

Recursive code, not working:

```
def out_of_orders(lst):
    if(lst[1]<lst[0]):
      print(lst[1])
      return 
    else:
      lst1=lst[1:len(lst)]      
      out_of_orders(lst1)
```

Comment: You need a base case of `len(lst)==1`, otherwise your code will throw some errors.

Comment: What does *"not working"* mean? I can see a clear `TypeError`, so **why don't you mention that**?! What have *you done* to figure it out? What output (or errors) do you get?

Comment: "inconsistens use of tabs.."

Comment: And if nothing is out of order, this returns... ?

Comment: @micmic so why not mention that? And why not *fix* the indentation? Typos are not on-topic here.

Comment: the same error message

Comment: You have not written the iterative variant... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374621/first-in-wrong-order-on-a-list-python/24374767#24374767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the conditional syntax used in Python 2.5 onwards.

```
def out_of_orders(lst):
    return lst[1] if (lst[1] < lst[0]) else out_of_orders(lst[1:])
```

Of course you'll have to test if the sub-array is to small (everything in the correct order), so full example would be:

```
lst = [1,5,17,12,24]

def out_of_orders(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return None
    return lst[1] if (lst[1] < lst[0]) else out_of_orders(lst[1:])

print out_of_orders(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def out_of_orders(my_list,last_checked=None):
    if last_checked is not None and last_checked > my_list[0]:
       return my_list[0]
    if len(my_list) > 1:
        return out_of_orders(my_list[1:],my_list[0])
```

I think that will work at least

Comment: I need to get only a string to the function

Comment: `out_of_orders([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,8,9])`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
lst1=lst[1:len(str)]
```

with:

```
lst1=lst[1:]
```

and it'll work (you probably used `str` as a debug tool and forgot to modify your code after removing it).

**Comment**: you shouldn't assume the list has at least two items (the first `if`).

```
def out_of_orders(lst):
    if(lst[1]<lst[0]):
      print(lst[1])
      return 
    else:
      lst1=lst[1:]      
      out_of_orders(lst1)

out_of_orders([1,5,17,12,24])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
12
```

Answer (score 0):

You recursive code *does actually run*, although not in all circumstances. You have several problems:

```
def out_of_orders(lst):
    if(lst[1]<lst[0]): # what if len(lst) < 2?
      print(lst[1]) # why print the number...
      return # ... then return nothing?
    else: # why 'else' - if the 'if' was met, you've already returned
      lst1=lst[1:len(lst)] # no need to assign this one line before using it     
      out_of_orders(lst1) # call recursively but ignore value returned
```

Functions in Python should generally `return` rather than `print` the value - it's then up to the caller to decide whether user feedback is required. This function should really look like:

```
def out_of_order(lst):
    """Return the first number in lst that's out of order."""
    if len(lst) > 1:
        if lst[0] > lst[1]:
            return lst[1]
        return out_of_orders(lst[1:])
```

where the slice `[1:]` means "from index 1 until we run out". Note that this will either return the first "out of order" number, or `None`. Example usage:

```
>>> print(out_of_order([1, 2, 3]))
None
>>> print(out_of_order([1, 3, 2]))
2
>>> print(out_of_order([3, 1, 2]))
1
```

Now the caller gets to decide whether to `print` the value, or use it in further calculations.

---

Also, your iterative version has problems with edge cases, consider:

```
>>> out_of_order([-3, -2, -1])
-3
```

A possible fix:

```
def out_of_order(lst):
    before = None
    for y in lst:
        if before is not None and y < before:
            return y
        before = y
```